# Is it possible to have a batch file as a binary element type in Wix?

Tags: wix, windows-installer

Here's my wix

```
<Binary Id="B.RenameFiles" SourceFile="RenameFiles.bat"/>
<CustomAction Id="CA.RenameFiles" BinaryKey="B.RenameFiles"
              ExeCommand="RenameFiles.bat" Execute="immediate" Return='ignore'/>

<InstallExecuteSequence>
    <Custom Action="CA.RenameFiles" Before="InstallValidate"></Custom>
</InstallExecuteSequence>
```

This doesn't work and spits out an error in the msi log "A program required for this install to complete could not be run". I'm not really sure if this is possible or if binary is only for use with exe's and dll's etc.

The way i'm doing it at the moment is to install the bat file and then run it from there but it would be neater if I could use it as a binary instead and not install it on the local machine.

Thanks
Neil

Answer (score 5, accepted):

BAT files cannot be launched directly by Windows Installer custom actions. You need a custom action which uses [ShellExecute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb762153%28v=vs.85%29.aspx?ppud=4) to launch your BAT.

So you can't use a BAT as a Binary custom action.

Comment: Or just invoke what ShellExecute will run, namely run cmd.exe. (Of course doing that results in an ugly command window appearing briefly, so often custom code that invokes ShellExecute is nicer.)

Answer (score 2):

Agree with Cosmin, you cannot execute BAT from binary, however you can launch it (almost) at any time during installation with help of "CMD.exe /C " custom action, and even have it run hidden (without cmd.exe window), i.e. for deffered CA one can use:

```
<CustomAction Id="Set_CA_HiddenBAT" Property="CA_HiddenBAT" Value="&quot;cmd.exe&quot; /c &quot;[DirectoryWhereBatFileInstalled]Your.bat&quot;" />
<CustomAction Id="CA_HiddenBAT" BinaryKey="WixCA" DllEntry="CAQuietExec" Execute="deferred" Return="ignore" Impersonate="yes" />
```

Or if you want it visible:

```
<CustomAction Id="CA_LaunchBAT" Directory="DirectoryWhereToExecute" ExeCommand="CMD.exe /c &quot;[DirectoryWhereBatFileInstalled]Your.bat&quot;" Return="ignore" />
```

Note: Remember to run CA_HiddenBAT / CA_LaunchBAT after InstallFiles action and have added WixUtilExtension to your .wixproj:

```
<LinkerAdditionalOptions>-ext WixUtilExtension</LinkerAdditionalOptions>
<CompilerAdditionalOptions>-ext WixUtilExtension</CompilerAdditionalOptions>
```

There's also a way to launch BAT before InstallFile action, but this is tricky, let me know if you need this.